# pgpool-II connection pooling - ERROR: "MD5" authentication with pgpool failed

Tags: postgresql-9.1, rhel, pgpool

Using the following for just connection pooling no master_slave or replication: rhel 6, postgresql 9.1.9, & pgpool-II 3.1.3 (also tried 3.2.5)

Followed solution suggested in http://www.pgpool.net/pipermail/pgpool-general/2013-May/001773.html

After following the instructions for MD5 I also tried setting both pg_hba.conf and pool_hba.conf to trust for local and subnet, but still get the following error when attempting to connect to the pool locally:

ERROR:  "MD5" authentication with pgpool failed for user foo

Tried locally on Fedora 18 with pg9.2 and pgpool from Fedora repo and worked right out of the box.

At the end of all routes suggested everywhere I could find.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you found any soultions yet?

Comment: no solution yet.  We're going to begin testing our upgrade to Postgres 9.3 so maybe we'll leap frog the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After having hit the same problem the solution was to change ownership of the pool_passwd file to postgres.

Even though this file has a 644 permission, if owner isn't postgres you'll always get the aforementioned error. I guess this file's owner and the user running pgpool must match.

I'm running PosgreSQL 9.2 and pgpool-II 3.3.2, BTW.